# How to show global instability of a system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider the system:

$
\dot x_1 = x_2
$

$
\dot x_2 = {x_1}^2
$

It is obviously unstable, I say that because by inspection the derivative of $x_2$ can never be negative.

How can we concretely show that, in the general case? If we were to prove stability we can use Lyapunov, but we cannot use that in the opposite way.

Comment: Do you mean stability at the origin?

Comment: The system is globally unstable, I am asking for a methodology that allows us to show that the system is globally or locally unstable in a formal way.
In the current example the only equilibrium is at the origin.
I don't know if I answered your question.

Comment: Can you show that the "negative" of the system, i.e. $\dot{x}_1 = -x_2, \dot{x}_2 = -x_{1}^2$ has a global attractor at the origin?

Comment: That is a beautiful insight, I did not think of that. Intuitionally it makes sense, but I cannot make a formal argument.

Comment: @avs has the right answer. Consider the "time-reversed" system, and that if you go backwards in time you will flow to the origin (the fix-point), from infinity. And so if you go forward... you are going to infinity. You can also do linear stability analysis, I don't see a problem with that?

Comment: @Steve Helm:  a linear analysis breaks down at $(0, 0)$ because the Jacobean of the system is singular at that point.  If I follow through with an answer, I'll write on that point.

Comment: @RobertLewis good point, missed that. Do you see any alternatives to looking at the time-reversed system? Just out of curiosity

Comment: I would accept an answer that rigorously presents the reverse time approach. Also, wouldn't local stability analysis only show local instability (singular Jacobian nonwithstanding)? We are interested in showing global isntability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy way to find out what the trajectories of your system look like: you just need to show that it is a Hamiltonian system.

---

### Sketching the phase portrait

A system

\begin{cases}
\dot{x}_1 = f(x_1,x_2) \\
\dot{x}_2 = g(x_1,x_2) \\
\end{cases}

is said to be Hamiltonian if there exists a smooth, real-valued function of two variables $H(x_1,x_2)$ such that $\partial H/\partial x_1 = g(x_1,x_2)$ and $\partial H/\partial x_2 = -f(x_1,x_2)$. For your system, we need $H$ to satisfy $\partial H/\partial x_1 = x_1^2$ and $\partial H/\partial x_2 = -x_2$. A quick integration tells us that any function of the form

$$
H(x_1,x_2) = \frac{x_1^3}{3} - \frac{x_2^2}{2} + C\qquad\qquad (C\in\mathbb{R}),
$$

does the job (we'll just choose $C = 0$ for simplicity). Now, Hamiltonian systems are interesting because their trajectories actually lie on the contour curves $H(x_1,x_2) = k$. If we plot all curves whose equation is $x_1^3/3 - x_2^2/2 = k$, for all real values of $k$, we have actually sketched the phase portrait!

Doing it for a few values of $k$ will produce something like this ($x_1$ is on the $x$-axis, $x_2$ on the $y$-axis):

[image]

---

### Presence of a stable manifold

Now that we know how the flow looks like, we just need to find the direction of the arrows. For $k\neq 0$, every trajectory is a smooth curve of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contains points arbitrarily far away from the origin, a fact that becomes obvious once we rewrite $x_1^3/3 - x_2^2/2 = k$ as:

$$
x_1 = \Bigl(\frac{3}{2}x_2^2 + 3k\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{3}};
$$

here it can be noted that $x_1\to+\infty$ when $x_2\to\pm\infty$. You also know that phase points are forced to move monotonically on their trajectories: they cannot just "stop" midway or, worse, reverse their path and start moving backwards. This means that ***almost*** every initial condition will eventually go to infinity, thus proving the instability of your fixed point.

But pay attention to my *"almost"*: what I said fails for $k=0$, when the contour line is

$$
x_1 = \sqrt[3\,]{\frac{3}{2}}x_2^{2/3}.
$$

In my picture, it's the one with a cusp at $(0,0)$. This equation does not represent a trajectory! It actually represents the union of ***three*** different orbits: the fixed point at the origin, and the two remaining branches of the curve. Now, $\dot{x_2} > 0$ in the fourth quadrant: this means that if you choose an initial condition on the lower portion of that contour line, the phase point will flow upwards until it gets close to the origin, which cannot be crossed because it is an equilibrium point; so the phase point will just slow down, always approaching the fixed point but never quite making it there.

Saying it rigorously, that line is the ***stable manifold*** of $(0,0)$.

Comment: Beautiful explanation, I was unaware of the system being a Hamiltonian one. However, this does not seem to be a universal method for proving the instability of the system. It only applies for Hamiltonian system, correct?

Comment: Yes, the key is that *this* system is Hamiltonian. For a general method, the reverse time approach that was discussed in comments seems to be the most fitting. Though not for this specific system, I think: judging by its phase portrait, reversing the sense of time would not make things easier. The origin would still be a nasty, nonlinear fixed point that keeps repelling almost all nearby trajectories away.

Comment: Very clear. I might ask a different question, with a non Hamiltonian system, just to see an example of the time inversion technique.